# only last array element is written properly

Tags: php, mysql

```
$str = "5ad46120704cf.jpg
5ad46120708b7.jpg
5ad4612070c9f.jpg
5ad46120700e7.jpg";

$arr = explode("\n", $str);
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    $sqlb = "select * from banners where fname = '" . $el . "' limit 1";
    $stb = $db->prepare($sqlb);
    $stb->execute();
    $row = $stb->fetch();
    $items .= "<img class='bsingle' src = '../banners/" . $row['fname'] . "' alt='img'>\n";
}
echo $items;
```

Result:

```
<img class='bsingle' src = '../banners/' alt='img'>
<img class='bsingle' src = '../banners/' alt='img'>
<img class='bsingle' src = '../banners/' alt='img'>
<img class='bsingle' src = '../banners/5ad46120700e7.jpg' alt='img'>
```

Why only lyast `bsingle` has its full source value?

I checked in table - there is no empty cells.

Any help?

Comment: instead of firing queries in a loop rather collect your ids and then fire 1 query using `IN(....)`

Comment: As your code is written, it is very open to SQL Injection - a major security risk. Never, ever create a SQL query by concatenating strings. Always use parametrised versions.

Comment: You aren't testing the result of the query for errors or empty results of the query.  Wrap the ```$items .= "<img...``` line in an if statement: ```if($row) {``` to be sure you are getting results from the query.

Comment: I don't get why you make a query to get `fname` when you already have that and search with that? Also you use `prepare` without binding variables and you are open to sql injection attacks

Comment: While I agree with @Dragonthoughts point about sql injection, in this specific example, it shouldn't be a concern since the query doesn't use data submitted from $_GET or other outside sources.

Comment: @SloanThrasher It still is not a good practice because the source could change in the future or the example here might be simplified to not include useless code to the question

Comment: Do you have to use a newline to split on? Is it ok to use a comma separated line and explode on the comma?

Comment: @ArthurHylton, I treid with comma and it works. What is the problem with new line separator, pls?

Comment: @blueSky I cannot pinpoint the problem with the newline I just know they tend to be finicky in different environments so that's why my first guess was them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess new line is maybe \r\n and if you just split by the \n the \r is still in it

Work with constant EOL would fix it otherwise try trim()

depending on system the end of line is \r\n or \n
php uses \n
most systems use \r\n

example:

```
 $str = 'LINE1'.EOL.'LINE2'.EOL;
 $arr = explode(EOL, $str);
```

also you could use preg_split instead of explode and work with both variants

http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php

```
 $lines = preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/",$content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess new line is maybe \r\n and if you just split by the \n the \r is still in it

Work with constant EOL would fix it
otherwise try trim()

Comment: I tried with comma and it works. What is the problem with new line separator, pls? Could you give me an EOL example?